# imagemagik make order wrong at 10th frame . like 1st frame 10th frame 2nd frame

Tags: imagemagick

`convert -delay 100 -loop 0 010-*.png Yannimation.gif`

> 010-0.png
>   010-2.png
>   010-3.png
>   010-4.png
>   010-5.png
>   010-6.png
>   010-7.png
>   010-8.png
>   010-9.png
>   010-10.png
>   010-11.png
>   010-12.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not ImageMagick, it's the normal collating sequence. To see, run

```
ls 010-*
```

and you'll get the same result. Replace `ls` with `DIR` on Windows.

The solution is either to zero-pad your frame numbers:

```
010-01
010-02
010-03
```

or to explicitly enumerate them in the correct order on the commandline

```
convert 010-1.png 010-2.png ...
```